# How to get the "To" receipt from email headers?

Tags: email, email-client

I'm developing an email client and just found that some emails do not have a "To" header field thus I don't 'know' who's the email intended for. Only a "From" and "CC" is provided and sometimes a "`For`" field. Is there any standard how to extract email address that the email is intended for ? (e.g. if `To` is missing look for `For`, if that's missing too look for turkeys :). See the sample below from an email I've just got.

```
 Return-Path: salfe@ono.com
        Received: from smtp2.ono.com ([62.42.230.179]) by mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmxus002)
         with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 0MQRb8-1XLJaM3en6-00Tmzn for
         <aneste@lobbyist.com>; Mon, 09 Jun 2014 11:27:43 +0200
        X-CTCH-RefID: str=0001.0A0B0203.53957E0C.00D9,ss=1,re=0.000,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,cl=1,cld=1,fgs=0
        X-CTCH-VOD: Unknown
        X-CTCH-Spam: Unknown
        Received: from PCRafaelRomero (85.137.226.62) by smtp2.ono.com (8.6.122.04) (authenticated as sanromero)
                id 5385D185003E1FAE for aneste@lobbyist.com; Mon, 9 Jun 2014 11:27:40 +0200
        From: <salfe@ono.com>
        Cc: <aneste@lobbyist.com>
        Subject: Reservation.
        Date: Mon, 9 Jun 2014 11:27:27 +0200
        Message-ID: <3f4001cf83c5$s$2a88d6a0$@com>
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
            boundary="----=_NextPart_000_3F41_01CF83D5.D1B66CE0"
        X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0
        Thread-Index: Ac+DxFZYas1DTYB/S/anWwcW8Cz4Ag==
        Content-Language: es
        X-Antivirus: avast! (VPS 140608-1, 08/06/2014), Outbound message
        X-Antivirus-Status: Clean
        Envelope-To: <aneste@lobbyist.com>
```

Even worse it seems that some emails have a wrong "To" but the email was delivered to my inbox anyway due the "For" header. I'm not sure how I can detect that unless I look in DB to see  if the "To" email is actually one of mine.

Comment: Have you checked the RFC? Googled?  Gene Spafford did some research years ago (not sure if it was published) that indicated that headers were unreliable.  Have you experimented with sending email without a to: header?  If you've already discovered that the TO: header is not reliable, why are you asking the question?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I've checked the IMAP specifications but ( http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501 ) as I'm using it to build the email client but there is not much about the reliability of the headers.

Comment: all the question was edited. I'm quite surprised that there is no "To" header at all... why would someone send such badly formatted headers ?

Comment: The only header you can really trust is the first Received header that your local MTA put on... in there you can see that it was received for <aneste@lobbyist.com>... and you cant guarantee all MTAs will put that header there in all cases.